# jQuery: using delay() and prepend()

Tags: jquery, delay, prepend

In the following code the last line doesn't work in my way:

```
$('button.goal').click(function () {
 $('div.scorer_away').animate({
  width: 'hide',
  opacy: 'hide'
  }, 'slow')
 .delay(2500)
 .animate({
  width: 'show',
  opacy: 'show'
  }, 'slow');
 $('span.scorer_away').delay(3000).prepend('<img src="chofbauer.png" alt="" />');
```

How can I make it work, that the prepend()-function adds the new image AFTER 3 sec (because after 2,5 sec the container, where the img prepends is hidden)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`.delay()` only works with jQuery `fx methods`. `.prepend()` is not one of those.

You can workaround it like

```
$('span.scorer_away').delay(3000).show(1, function(){
    $(this).prepend('<img src="chofbauer.png" alt="" />');
});
```

Actually you would have to create your own [.queue()](http://api.jquery.com/queue/) for a "clean" solution.

Another way to accomplish that task is to use javascripts native `setTimeout()`.

```
setTimeout(function(){
   $('span.scorer_away').prepend('<img src="chofbauer.png" alt="" />');
}, 3000);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try using `setTimeout`:

```
function myfunc() { $('span.scorer_away').prepend('<img...>') };   
setTimeout( myfunc, 3000 );
```